# assign value to pandas column depending on variable

Tags: python, pandas

very simple one and despite several google searches I could not find an answer (somewhat Python newbie). I would like to assign either 1 or 0 to a panda data frame depending on some variable. here is the pseudo code:

```
variable = 5

df['column name'] = if variable == 5 then 1 else 0
```

any pointer very much welcome thanks.

this would work but feels a bit long wounded?:

```
if a == 5:
  df['column name'] = 1
else:
  df['column name'] = 0
```

Comment: so your column is just a constant for every row?

Comment: yes it is really only one row but is replicated concatenated down stream

Comment: That (updating values one row at a time) doesn't sound like something you should do with a Pandas dataframe. You should calculate all the values, then do `df['col_name'] = [value0, value1,...]`.

Comment: it make sense in my use case and is a poc anyway. as i said this is only assigned to one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly convert the boolean to integer and assign it as the column value

```py
df['column name'] = int(variable==5)
```

Above works for the specific case, but you can have conditional expression as well:

```py
df['column name'] = X if variable == 5 else Y
```

where X is the value for True, and Y is value for False